# What is the difference: 'was seated' vs 'seated'?

Tags: past-tense

Could you please explain what is the difference between this two:

> Mr. Sherlock Holmes **was seated** at the breakfast table.
>
> Mr. Sherlock Holmes **seated** at the breakfast table.

Comment: The difference is in transitivity (i.e., whether the verb *seat* can take a direct object). Check [the dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/seat) to see which way *seat* is most commonly used.

Answer (score 2):

The second one doesn't make sense.  [*To seat **something** or **someone*** means "to place **something** on a seat or seats, or cause **someone** to sit down".](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/seat)  So if Sherlock Holmes was sitting at the table, then he **was seated**.  That construction is the passive voice (to be + the past participle, which is *seated*) in the past tense (*was* seated).  We often use the passive voice to describe something as though the participle was an adjective: he was tall, he was tired, he was seated, etc.

If you say "Sherlock Holmes seated..." that means he put someone or something else in a seat.  But since the sentence doesn't have an object (what did he put in a seat?) it doesn't make sense.

The verb could also be used reflexively; e.g., "Sherlock Holmes seated **himself** behind a desk," is a valid sentence because the object (*himself*) is present.